# Checking if all items in a list contain (or rather are) the same string.

Tags: python, list, function

I'm almost done making a tic tac toe game, and now I want to write a function that checks if there is a winner. My board is a list of lists :

```
lst = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

def board():
print (lst[0:3])
print (lst[3:6])
print (lst[6:])

['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
['7', '8', '9']
```

And this is the function I use for the gameplay:

```
def move2():
    move2=(input('Player 2: Type a number!'))
    for x in lst:
    if move2 == x:
        lst[int(move2)-1] = 'o'
        board()
        move()
    elif move2.isdigit() and move2 not in lst:
        print('Not that number!')
        break
        board()
        move2()
    elif not move2.isdigit():
        print('Not that number!')
        break
        board()
        move2()
```

I then split up the original list for the possible winning scenarios:

```
climax1 = lst[0:3]
climax2 = lst[3:6]
climax3 = lst[6:] 
climax4 = [lst[0],lst[3],lst[6]]
climax5 = [lst[1],lst[4],lst[7]]
climax6 = [lst[2],lst[5],lst[8]]
climax7 = [lst[0],lst[4],lst[8]]
```

And tried this to check if any of these contain either all 'x's or all 'o's:

```
def conclusion():
    if all(item == 'x' for item in climax1) or all(item == 'x' for item in climax2) or all(item == 'x' for item in climax3) or all(item == 'x' for item in climax4) or all(item == 'x' for item in climax5) or all(item == 'x' for item in climax6) or all(item == 'x' for item in climax7):
    print('Player 1 wins!')
   elif all(item == 'o' for item in climax1) or all(item == 'o' for item in climax2) or all(item == 'o' for item in climax3) or all(item == 'o' for item in climax4) or all(item == 'o' for item in climax5) or all(item == 'o' for item in climax6) or all(item == 'o' for item in climax7):
    print('Player 2 wins!')
else:
    move()
```

But when I try to integrate this into the function for the gameplay it says it's not defined. And when I try something like:

```
all('o' == item for item in climax1)
```

It returns False every time, even if all the items in that list are an 'o'.

Sorry for the long chunks of code. If any of you have any advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `climax1.count('x') == len(climax1)`

Comment: Your indentation is messed up. You need to fix that. Correct indentation is vital in Python.

Comment: As blueberryfields says `climax` 1 to 3 won't do what you want because they're static copies of the `lst` data. And you forgot the other diagonal line: `[lst[2], lst[4], lst[6]]`. Also, you should put all those `climax` lists into a list of lists. Then you'll be able to check each one in a loop. Actually, there's a simpler strategy because if you check after each move you don't need to check every line to see if there's a winner. But I guess you can implement that strategy in your next version. :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice guys, but can anyone explain why it says that the function 'conclusion' is not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your assignments:

```
climax1 = lst[0:3]
climax2 = lst[3:6]
climax3 = lst[6:]
```

copy the original list; so when you're updating list, you're not updating the copies. Fix that and your code will work.

(to debug, try adding `print(climax1)` as a debug statement)

Comment: blueberryfields if that's the case with these three then how come it works with the others?

Comment: I reformatted the lists like this:                                                                          climax1 = [lst[0],lst[1],lst[2]]
    climax2 = [lst[3],lst[4],lst[5]]
    climax3 = [lst[6],lst[7],lst[8]] 
    climax4 = [lst[0],lst[3],lst[6]]
    climax5 = [lst[1],lst[4],lst[7]]
    climax6 = [lst[2],lst[5],lst[8]]
    climax7 = [lst[0],lst[4],lst[8]]
    climax8 = [lst[2],lst[4],lst[6]]      But I still get an error saying the function 'conclusion' is not defined.